# Confused on how to implement HMACSHA1 in C# .NET coming from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I am using the crypto-js library to implement the HMACSHA1 for my javascript code

the code looks like this

```
const hash1 = require("crypto-js");

let signature = "application_id=3610&auth_key=aDRceQyTXSYEdJU&nonce=6304033672&timestamp=1623098533&user[login]=john@mail.com&user[password]=123456789"

let key = "dBV2PdhYMnruSMb"
let hash = hash1.HmacSHA1(signature, key).toString()

console.log(hash)

//which prints 
467280c4cb82fc97bd04c51d8a846446ad6e82e1
```

this obviously is pretty easy in javascript. But then I tried using the same exact string and key in c# and it prints out a completely different string. I am lost and don't know how to solve this issue.

Here is my attempt to implement this in C#

```
string signSession = "application_id=3610&auth_key=aDRceQyTXSYEdJU&nonce=6304033672&timestamp=1623098533&user[login]=john@mail.com&user[password]=123456789"

string key = "dBV2PdhYMnruSMb="

//convert the session signature string to a byte array
            byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signSession.ToString());

            var apiKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
             
            //Generate a HMACSHA1 signature
            using(HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(apiKey))
            {
                byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
                string base64Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
                Console.WriteLine(base64Signature);
                session.Signature = base64Signature;
            }

//And this prints 
sztTnSTv2xvuA7pPXxk2cKMP0Eo=

//which is wrong. It should be the same as the javascript result
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong here and is my C# implementation right?

Comment: Of course it's different, your JS implementation has a hex encoded output but in your C# implementation you're base64 encoding the result.

Comment: And in JS you directly pass the key while in C# you base64 decode it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `key` is different. While crypto-js expects a string, C# expects a byte array. You shouldn't use `FromBase64String()` but `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`. As @jps mentioned in the comment

> Of course it's different, your JS implementation has a hex encoded
> output but in your C# implementation you're base64 encoding the
> result.

you should convert the byte-array to a hex-string like so

```
string signSession = "application_id=3610&auth_key=aDRceQyTXSYEdJU&nonce=6304033672&timestamp=1623098533&user[login]=john@mail.com&user[password]=123456789";

string key = "dBV2PdhYMnruSMb";

//convert the session signature string to a byte array
byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signSession);

var apiKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

//Generate a HMACSHA1 signature
using (HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(apiKey))
{
    byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
    string hexSignature = BitConverter.ToString(signatureBytes).ToLowerInvariant().Replace("-", "");
    Console.WriteLine(hexSignature);
    session.Signature = hexSignature;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me hours of my life. It would have taken me a long time to figure that out. Sometimes javascript makes things too easy.